# How to get list of variable names from Java file?

Tags: java, file, variables

How can I get the list of variables from a Java file? So far, I've started by reading the file and splitting each word using spaces. unfortunately, this returns all import statements, comments..etc

```
public ArrayList<String> getVariables(String javaFilePath) {
    ArrayList<String> variableList = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        // creating a buffer reader from the file path
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(javaFilePath)));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] variables = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String variable : variables) {

                variableList.add(variable);

            }

        }

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("This is FileNotFoundException error : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("This is IOException error : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return variableList;
}
```

For example: I've java file saved on C:\Sample.java. And it's code looks like this:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Sample {
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

And the output using the above method returns the following:

```
package
com.test;

import
java.io.File;
import
java.io.FileInputStream;

public
class
Sample
{
String
name;

public
String
getName()
{

return
name;
}

public
void
setName(String
name)
{

this.name
=
name;
}

}
```

**Question:** how do I modify my method shown above in order to get only variables. For example: I want only "name" & "Sample" for the above class.

Comment: It won't be this easy, you need to get some java parser. For example https://javaparser.org/

Comment: why would you want `Sample`? Do you want method parameters as well or only fields? Both are variables. What about parameters of lambda functions, etc!? What if I define `String one,two;`, etc.

Comment: You'll definitely need a proper Java parser.

Comment: @luk2302 I want only the the class names and field names only. If it's defined as String one,two;  then I want the variables as"one","two"

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj thankyou I need something like that.I'll definitely take a look at that

Comment: A java parser would be the first option, though for the example from the description it could work by (1) first take the substring starting at index of first `{` (2) then split by `;` (3) then skip the lines between the lines ending with `{` or `}` (4) and then split by space

Comment: @ValentinCarnu well, looking at only one example is meaningless because my code always returning you exactly "name" & "Sample" would be equally as good. As soon as something like local variables and / or nested (or anonymous) classes come into play whatever OP tries without a parser is going to fail.

Comment: @luk2302 first option should be a java parser, for example purpose or experimenting, the solution described in my previous comment could be something to try

Comment: You're not writing a code inspection tool, are you ? - In that case you may be better of writing a plugin for IntelliJ. (you can run intellij inspections from the command prompt.)